# Preset data inputs at 74HC163

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

After looking at [datasheet for 74HC/T163](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT163.pdf) devices from Nexperia, I have some doubts regarding the input D3-0 pins of the device. If you follow the logic from these inputs (logic diagram at page 3), at the preset condition outputs will be loaded with BITWISE NOT of D[3:0] while in the timing sequence at page 6 it is loaded to input data bits itself.

For comparison, at the [74HC/T161 datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC161.pdf) there is no NOT gate at the D0-3 inputs while the logic diagram at page 3 of both are identical (except for their reset pin MRn). As far as I know the only difference between these two parts is their reset behavior.

It can be somewhat correct to consider NOT of inputs because for example when you want to build a counter which divides by 10, you can simply load the inputs with 0b1010; then the counter starts from 5 and counts up to 15. For example look at [this example](https://slidetodoc.com/presentation_image_h/0df6558d0409b43957b439c8b33c9f26/image-49.jpg). The problem is that this is not
in accordance with function table of the device.

I'm kind of confused about this because a datasheet this old cannot be incorrect. There is also same discrepancy in older version of the datasheet: [here](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/364/74HCT163-pdf.php) and [here](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/364/74HC_HCT161-pdf.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm kind of confused about this because a datasheet this old cannot be incorrect.

If it happens, it must be true. One of those data sheets must be incorrect.

Well spotted.

I'm not going to trace the through the many, many, inversions to see which is correct, and presumably the proof readers at NXP have not done either. Errors can persist in data sheets for ages. FWIW, I think the 161 is correct, and the 163 is in error.

Do bear in mind that those diagrams are not the source material from which the parts are designed, but illustrations to comfort the nervous designer who doesn't quite trust the timing diagrams or the IEC logic symbols, so there's no strong pressure to make sure they are correct. Compare the diagrams with those in the TI datasheet for the same part for instance, they are totally different.

If the IEC logic diagram, the function, the timing diagrams, the designer's expectation, and whatever HDL files NXP provide to programmers of automatic test equipment to test boards using these things, all agree, then to misquote MeatLoaf (rip) 'five out of six ain't bad.' It's probably because all these other media agree that nobody has studied the internal diagram with the thoroughness you have.

It would be interesting, and I'll leave this as an exercise for you, to trawl back through 161 and 163 data sheets of earlier years and for their many different manufacturers, to see which are in error. When you done that, post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: [This datasheet](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/ixkxuxwpjn/ONSMS12178-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) from On Semi (or well, probably from Motorola originally) seems to use the same logic circuit, see p.9.